# How do I make background image transition smooth in my project?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building my first javascript project and making a random quote generator. I want to implement a smooth background transition in my project but I am not able to achieve that.

I already tried messing with transition property and animate property but nothing seems to work.

HTML code:

```
<body>
    <div id="quote-box" class="quotes">
        <div id="text"></div>
        <div id="author"></div>
        <div class="links">
            <a id="twitter-quote" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <a id="tumblr-quote" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=${quote}" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-tumblr"></i></a>
            <a id="new-quote" href="#">New Quote</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="./main.js"></script>

</body>
```

CSS code:

```
body{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.quotes{
    position: absolute;
    width: 37.5rem;
    bottom: 60px;
    left: -37.5rem;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding: 1.4rem;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-top-right-radius: .3rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: .3rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: justify;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    opacity: 0;
}

.slide{
    transform: translateX(37.5rem);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
```

JavaScript Code:

```
function setupQuotes() {
    fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smartdev007/Avengers-Quote/master/quotes.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {

        function getRandomQuote() {
            if (quoteBox.classList.contains('slide')) {
                quoteBox.classList.remove('slide')
            }

            const randomIdx = parseInt(Math.random() * data.length);
            const { quote, author, url } = data[randomIdx];

            tweetBtn.setAttribute('href', `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=${quote}`);
            tumblrBtn.setAttribute('href', `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=${quote}`);

            setTimeout(() => {
                document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = `<span class="big-quote">&#8220;</span>
                ${quote}`;
                document.getElementById('author').innerHTML = `-${author}`;
                document.body.style.background = `url('${url}') no-repeat center top/cover`;
                quoteBox.classList.add('slide');
            }, 500)
          }

          newQuote.addEventListener('click', getRandomQuote);

          getRandomQuote();
        })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

Codepen link for the full project:
https://codepen.io/FuriousJK/pen/YMoNgZ

I am trying to achieve this kind of transition: https://codepen.io/bradtraversy/full/oVPBaa

Answer (score 1):

Add this to body:

```
 transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bybGew

Comment: It doesn't give the same result as the expected codepen result though. Is there no way to achieve that kind of transition in my project?

Comment: Yes you can have the same result by making the transition faster: background 0.4s  ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: background 0.4s  ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: background 0.4s  ease-in-out;

Comment: It's close but no the same though. We can still see the white background before another image loads, unlike the smooth transition showed in another project.

Comment: I don't get the white background before another image loads.

Comment: Well, that's strange :/